# vuejs basic conditional rendering issue

Tags: vue.js

I simply just want to show the span if the name is found in the data. If its not found in the data, I want the span to hide. I am using simply v-if or v-else.It is currently displaying "my name is in the data". But it is not. I basically will have some names...and want the "my name is in the data" to only display if the name is indeed there.

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
    FirstName:'Paul',
   
  },
  methods: {
    toggle: function(todo){
        todo.done = !todo.done
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">

 <span v-if="FirstName=='lu'||'John'||'Sue'">
  My Name is in the data
 </span><br>
 <span v-else>
   Not available
 </span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's better to do your conditionals like this

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
    FirstName:'Paul',
   
  },
  methods: {
    toggle: function(todo){
        todo.done = !todo.done
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">

 <span v-if="FirstName=='lu'|| FirstName=='John' || FirstName=='Sue'">
  My Name is in the data
 </span>
 <span v-else>
   Not available
 </span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

In Javascript, non-empty strings are regarded as `true` [("truthy")](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Truthy) in boolean expressions, and equality is of a higher [operator precedence](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Operator_Precedence) than boolean OR (`||`). Therefore, as a boolean, your expression reads as though it were:

```js
(FirstName=='lu') || true || true
```

The above expression  is always `true`, so your element is always visible.

---

As in [Vavon's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72145576/1426891), you'll need it to read:

```js
FirstName=='lu'||FirstName=='John'||FirstName=='Sue'
```

or with spaces:

```js
FirstName == 'lu' || FirstName == 'John' || FirstName == 'Sue'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use [`Array.includes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes#syntax) in your [`v-if` condition](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/conditional.html?redirect=true) to check whether `FirstName` is in any set of values.

```js
<span v-if="['lu', 'John', 'Sue'].includes(FirstName)">
  My Name is in the data 
 </span>
 <span v-else>
   Not available
 </span>
```